# Get names from first JSON object

Tags: arrays, json, object

I would like to save names from first JSON object instead of two.

```
var json = [ 
 {"name":"James","age":"17","Gender":"Male"},{"name":"Bobee","age":"22","Gender":"Male"}
];


$.each(json, function () {
   $.each(this, function (name) {
      console.log(name); //this outputs two times name, two times age and two times gender
   });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

just use map function

```
var result =  json.map(function(x){return x.name});

console.log(result)
```

Comment: I meant that I want output as follows: "name","age",gender"

Comment: do you want a list

Comment: This is what I want: ["name","age","gender"].

Comment: json.filter(function(x){result.push(x.name,x.age,x.Gender);});

Comment: result:[ 'James',
  '17',
  'Male',
  'Bobee',
  '22',
  'Male' ]

Comment: No values, just names. And names only once, not twice.

Comment: you want to print only keys?

Comment: can you write your response that you want?

Comment: ["name","age","gender"] , only keys

Comment: in that case just use Object.keys(json[0])